# ASP.NET Core MVC - System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

This is the description of the error :

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context
> instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance
> that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to
> use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may
> occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or
> wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency
> injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care
> of disposing context instances. Object name: 'AppDbContext'.'

I am trying to set database records into two objects which I have created in my controller file and use it for excel report generation. But when I click the generate report button, it gives this error.

Here is the code for the controller methods:

```cs
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        private static IEnumerable<Feedback> sheetfeedbacks;

 public AdminController(AppDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
           _db = db;
           _userManager = userManager;
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }


public IActionResult FeedbackMgmt()
{
    ParentForApply ParentVM = new ParentForApply();
    var records = _db.FeedbackData;
    ParentVM.FeedbackList = records;           
    sheetfeedbacks = records;
    return View(ParentVM);
}

public IActionResult ReportFeedback()
{           
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Feedback Data");
        var CurrentRow = 1;
        #region Header
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 1).Value = "Sr. No";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 2).Value = "Full Name";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 3).Value = "Suggestions";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 4).Value = "Contact No";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 5).Value = "Email Id";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 6).Value = "City";
        worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 7).Value = "State";
        

        #endregion

        #region  Body
        foreach (var fback in sheetfeedbacks)
        {
            CurrentRow++;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 1).Value = CurrentRow - 1;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 2).Value = fback.FullName;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 3).Value = fback.Suggestions;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 4).Value = fback.ContactNo;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 5).Value = fback.EmailId;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 6).Value = fback.City;
            worksheet.Cell(CurrentRow, 7).Value = fback.State;        
            
        }
        

        #endregion

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            var content = stream.ToArray();

            return File(
                content,
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                "Feedback Data.xlsx"
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Above mentioned error pops up at **ReportFeedback()** method.

Comment: Could you provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: Something seems off - where is the DbContext in any of this code?

Comment: Try using `Async Task` & `await` in your controller methods

Answer (score 1):

The only place you are using `AppDbContext` in your controller is at this line

```
var records = _db.FeedbackData;
```

And as long as you want to access the database then you need to use `Task` & `Await`
, that I suspect is the main cause for the error

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FeedbackMgmt()
{
    ParentForApply ParentVM = new ParentForApply();
    var records = await _db.FeedbackData.ToListAsync();
    ParentVM.FeedbackList = records;           
    sheetfeedbacks = records;
    return View(ParentVM);
}
```

Comment: var records = await _db.FeedbackData;
This line gives me an syntex error for missing a using directive or assembly reference

Comment: What does `_db.FeedbackData` should do? is it a table in your database? if you want to retrieve records for this table you should use `_db.FeedbackData.ToListAsync()`

Comment: yes it is. let me try this ToListAsync() method

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks a lot. you saved me a lot of vain efforts. it worked like I wanted it to. Thanks again 